# Django: How to serialize a custom field into a fixture and load it back

Tags: django, serialization, fixtures, custom-fields

I have a custom field with to_python and get_db_prep_value methods as defined below:

```
  def to_python(self, value):
    if not value:
      return None
    if isinstance(value, oauth2client.client.Credentials):
      return value
    return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(value))

  def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    return base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(value))
```

When I use dumpdata to dump this field, the values appear as:

```
"<oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object at XXXXXXXX"
```

What should I do with the custom field in order to dump it and load it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `value_to_string` method for the field. [Relevent django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-field-data-for-serialization)